# Parfor on a cluster : failure to recognize a function

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I try to run a simple task on different machines of a cluster.
My configuration has been validated (it's ok). When I run the code
on the 'local' configuration, it works. But when I use the cluster
configuration, I get the following error :

Error using parallel_function (line 598)
Undefined function 'lafunc' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error Stack : (No remote error stack)
Error in petittest (line 6)  --» (petittest is my program's name)
parfor it=1:200

I try to modify the code to use "dfeval" instead of the parfor loop,
but I got the same kind of result (unrecognize function lafunc).

How do I get the other workers in the cluster to recognize the function
lafunc that I manually defined ?

The code is the following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
laconfig='/home/matlab/fred/LACED_DC1.mat';
setmcruserdata('ParallelConfigurationFile',laconfig);

matlabpool open

parfor it=1:200

yo=lafunc(it);
disp(yo)

end

matlabpool close

%%%%%%%%%%%
```

where the lafunc function is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function [y]=lafunc(x)
y=x*x;
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Thanks a lot, every piece of info is useful to me!!

Comment: How, roughly, is your cluster arranged? Are you running this code on the head node? Does parfor work if you put built-in functions instead of lafunc?

Comment: @IanHincks Yes we are running the program on the head node of the cluster. The parfor does work with built-in functions, so I believe it is related to the fact that other workers don't see the hand-made function which is situated on the main node.

P.S. I found that it is possible to do something similar using the 'FileDependencies' option with dfeval, but I'd like to know if it is possible to do it with parfor. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm guessing that your nodes don't share a common file system, and so don't have the function lafunc in their path. So somehow you need to get that function onto each of the node's filesystems, or declare the function inline (`lafunc=@(x) x*x;` above the parfor loop). Or put the parfor loop inside of a function, and have lafunc as a subfunction. Those are all the options I can think of now.

Comment: @IanHincks : Finally the advice given in the other answer worked! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your MATLAB script on all worker nodes running in the same working directory, and that other directories with functions you need are included in the path. So you can specifically set the working directory and path in your script:

```
matlabpool open
cd workdir
addpath funcdir
...
```

After you run `matlabpool open` it will run all path related commands on all workers. See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bq__cs7-1.html#bq__cs7-5).

You can also open matlabpool with `'FileDependencies'` parameter so all the workers will know where to look for required files. See the documentation for [MATLABPOOL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/matlabpool.html).

Comment: The 'FileDependencies' in matlabpool was successful.
Thanks a lot, it will help a lot of people at the university here!!

Comment: Sorry to remind you, but please don't forget to accept/upvote answers that you found helpful.